# How to configure delay until condition is true in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a question about Jmeter delay, I created a test plan and in one step I make a call to DB using JDBC, and store the results in actual_vertica_results parameter (counts number of employees in temp table).
I want to configure Jmeter to Waite until actual_vertica_results will be 0.
(the table in DB deletes itself)
Can someone please advise how can I perform such scenario in Jmeter, today I am using constant timer for delay, and increase it manually each iteration to make sure all the data deleted.
How can I ask Jmeter making call to DB every 5 seconds and check  the results and only after all temp data deleted from the table to progress to the next step?
if someone can provide step by step scenario with PIC it will be very helpful
regards

[image]

Comment: Did you tried the While Controller?

Comment: No, is it the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put your JDBC Request sampler under the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${Actual_vertica_results}" != "0",)}
   ```
2. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler after your JDBC Request sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Target: `Current Thread`
   - Action: `Pause`
   - Duration: `5000`

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article for more information.

Comment: the only change is  ${__javaScript("${Actual_vertica_results_1}" != "0",)}

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about two options:

1. I guess the clean way would be to include a Transaction Controller + Constant Timer + While Controller (as Dmitri wrote - with condition `${__javaScript("${Actual_vertica_results}" != "0",)}`), so that JDBC request fires off in line with the timer delay:

[image]

2. The "nasty" way could be to use an anonymous code block in JDBC Request (Callable Statement as query type) and the code below (Oracle as an example):

> ```
> declare
>   var integer;
> begin
>   var := 1;
>   while var <> 0
>     loop
>       select count(rec) into var from test_count;
>       dbms_lock.sleep(5);
>     end loop;
> end;
> ```

but this assumes that you do not need the Actual_vertica_results variable for other purposes and your db user has granted privileges to execute a delay/sleep (on DBMS_LOCK package in Oracle example). Possibly you could also create a function in your database with a given return value (if you tend to some validations on different tables).

Answer (score 1):

Different solution:

- add next steps in another Thread group
- Check Run Thread group consequently checkbox in Test Plan
- Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) with Target Current Thread and Action Stop when count = 0

This way Thread group will execute until count = 0 and then continue to next steps in different Thread group

- You can add Loop Count Forever in first Thread Group if you need